# PhpStorm select next occurrence of symbol

Tags: ide, phpstorm

How can I select occurrences of variables in PhpStorm rather than just **any** text in the editor?

---

In PhpStorm <kbd>Alt + J</kbd> will select next occurrence in text like so:

[image]

Is there an action to select next occurrence of *symbol* (not just text)? like so:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to select next occurance of "symbol" you have to place your cursor on the word without selecting it and then hit `Alt + J`.

If you want to select the next occurance of text then you have to select the text first and then hit `Alt + J`.

So basically it behaves differently if you have selected a text or not.